# geom_emoji() function does not accept input if it's stored in a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, emoji

I am trying to include emojis in a plot created with R and ggplot2. I´m currently using the emoGG package, specifically the `geom_emoji()` function. The weird thing is that I can pass the emoji name as a character string but I cannot assign the character string to a variable and use that instead. This makes it impossible to automate the assignment with a lookup table. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
# Reproducible Example

# packages
library(emoGG)
library(ggplot2)

# Example (works)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_emoji(emoji="1f337")


# Doesn't work (Error: Not Found)
Pic <- "1f337"
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_emoji(emoji=Pic)

# Identical
identical("1f337",Pic)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the developer anticipated this use. The relevant section of their code [here on Github](https://github.com/dill/emoGG/blob/master/R/geom_emoji.R#L102-L108) assumes that you're passing a named parameter with a string literal all the time.

This code below will work for your use. But I don't think you can easily plot multiple emojis on a single plot using aesthetics as you would for other `ggplot2` based extensions. There may be other packages that plot symbols that might fit your needs.

```r
library(emoGG)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
Pic <- "1f337"
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  do.call(geom_emoji, list(emoji = Pic))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can actually plot multiple Emoji in one plot by just chaining multiple calls of geom_emoji() together and this will allow us to do it automatically :)

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!